Inequalities and averages
Dikshant writes down $2 k+1$ positive integers in a list where $k$ is a positive integer. The integers are not necessarily all distinct, but there are at least three distinct integers in the list. The average (mean) of all $2 k+1$ integers is itself an integer and appears at least once in the list. The average of the smallest $k+1$ integers in the list is within $\frac{1}{2025}$ of the average of the largest $k+1$ integers in the list. Determine the smallest possible value of $k$.
My approach : Let he numbers be
$a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq .... \leq a_{2k+1}$ and the average of them be $A$,
The average of the smallest $(k+1)$ numbers be " S "
and that of the largest $(k+1)$ numbers be " L "
Now,
according to the condition, $S<\frac{L}{2025}$ , right?
What do I do now?

What have you tried?  Suppose there are only three distinct numbers.  How big would $k$ have to be in that case?  That may not yield the optimal answer, but at least it is a start  Something you can try to improve on.

Note:  the condition means $L-S≤\frac 1{2025}$...it's an additive test, not a multiplicative one.

any other hints please?

My first hint was very strong.

I did n-1,n,n,n......,n+1. The average is n,which is present in the list.Now applying the condition,I get k>4049 I.e it is atleast 4050.Is this correct?

Yes, now can you argue that no other configuration can yield a smaller result?

yes I'm trying to minimise the difference of the averages.Any hint?

Well, you need an argument to show that adding a new value that isn't the average makes things worse, not better.

for minimising L-S,we need to make sure both of their values are as close to each other.We also need to make sure their average in present in the list.n-1,n,n....n,n+1 is the only list that satisfies this.So k is atleast 4050.Is this correct now?

I posted  a solution below.  I am getting $k=4049$ so check to see if I made an arithmetic error or if you did.  Of course,if we read the constraint as requiring that the difference between the two averages be strictly less than $\frac 1{2025}$, then $4050$ is correct.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
Suppose we had an optimal set.
Let $n$ denote the overall average.  We know $n$ is in the set, and we know that there must be at least one number $>n$ and one less than $n$. If $n+k$ is in the set for $k>1$ then we can lower the upper average by replacing it with $n+1$, hence we can produce an optimal set for which the only number in the set above $n$ must be $n+1$.  Similarly, we can produce an optimal set for which the only number in the set below $n$ must be $n-1$.
In the same spirit, we can arrange to have only one each of $n+1$ and $n-1$.  Indeed, if there were two copies of $n+1$, then we can reduce the upper average by replacing one of them by $n$.  By symmetry, we can produce an optimal set in which there is only one copy of $n-1$.
Thus our (possibly modified) optimal set consists of one each of $n-1$ and $n+1$, and $2k-1$ copies of $n$.
Given that, the lower average is $$\frac {n-1+kn}{k+1}=\frac {(k+1)n-1}n=1-\frac 1{k+1}$$
And the upper average is $$1+\frac 1{k+1}$$
Finally, the difference between the upper and lower averages is $\frac 2{k+1}$  so we want the least possible $k$ for which $$\frac 2{k+1}≤\frac 1{2025}\implies k=4049$$
